# I am getting an error when trying to XML serialize an object

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type ProfileChulbul was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterProfileDefinitionExportHolder.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
```

if you see '**ProfileChulbul**' is an object, I am trying to serialize

Comment: BreakHead, the question is still incredibly vague. Please post code for the class you are trying to serialize.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This happens when the type you're serializing has a property of a type that is not statically known to the serializer instance. For example, if the type `ProfileChulbul` has a base type, which is how it is referenced from what you're serializing, the serializer won't know how to work with it.

You have a couple options for resolving this problem:

- Add the `[XmlInclude(typeof(ProfileChulbul))]` attribute (and additional attributes for any other types that will be used) to `ProfileChulbul`'s base class
- Modify the class you use for serialization to use generics instead of Object
- Pass `typeof(ProfileChulbul)` (and any other types that will be used) into the serializer constructor at runtime, like so:

  `var knownTypes = new Type[] { typeof(ProfileChulbul), typeof(ProfileSomethingElse) };`

  `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheSerializableType), knownTypes);`

Comment: Thanx Daniel, Stack Overflow rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the part of the stacktrace "Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically", I would bet you are trying to serialize an interface or collection of interfaces?  Xml Serialization does not allow this, try marking the interface with the [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attributes.

Comment: So how should I do this, because the object I am getting to serialize is a generic object.

Comment: BreakHead, that's exactly what's causing the error then. Can you use generics instead of a plain old Object?

Comment: +1 i had the same experience :-( now i am using [sharpserializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) that can handle xml-(de-)serialisations.

Comment: @BreakHead, if you serialize an object, you must know the concrete types that are to be serialized.  Can you post some code to make it a bit clearer on what's going on?